# PostGIS: Could not choose the best candidate function between: public.st_geomfromgeojson( => json), public.st_geomfromgeojson( => jsonb)

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgrest

I've PostgREST in front of PostGIS and I want to call the [st_geomfromgeojson](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) function as described at https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html#stored-procedures.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://postgrest-host:port/rpc/st_geomfromgeojson' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}'
```

Getting error:

```
{"hint":"Try renaming the parameters or the function itself in the database so function overloading can be resolved","message":"Could not choose the best candidate function between: public.st_geomfromgeojson( => json), public.st_geomfromgeojson( => jsonb)"}
```

Is there a way I can supply the PostGIS function parameter in HTTP request so that `public.st_geomfromgeojson( => json)` is chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgREST has no way to differentiate between those two overloaded functions due to them having the same quantity of parameters with the same name but different data type.

A solution would be to create a wrapper function with a different name and call the `st_geomfromgeojson` function inside of it. Then you'd call the wrapper function instead to avoid the conflict.